# How to limit usage by user plans/role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity and I can manage the roles and authorization. My question is, how would you limit the usage from the plans, as with the "Authorize" atribute I can only limit full access to the action/controller?

My authorization is dynamic and I plan to add as many plans as needed and edit them in a control panel I created.

Example of what I want to achieve:

1. Basic plan can add 5 pics on its album.
2. Gold plan can add 10 pics on its album.
3. Premium plan can add unlimited pics on album.

Comment: asp.net-identity not only has roles, but also claims. try a claim `AllowedPictures` with value 5. you have to manually check it in your controller, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U just need a Role-Based Auth. U can do those things with `Claims`.
[That's the link for you](https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/role-based-and-claims-based-authorization-in-aspnet-core-using-policies-hands-on)

For a example, if user has a Gold plan you can give him a GoldRole and u can give him a as much role as you want it to be. If the user has Gold role so he can do those actions ;

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
        public IActionResult Profile()
        {
            int userID = getCurrentUser();
            var currentUser = _unitofworkShoppingUser.RepositoryShoppingUser.GetCurrenUserProfile(userID);
            var profileViewModel = new ProfileViewModel
            {
                ShoppingUsers = currentUser
            };
            return View(profileViewModel);
        }
```

In that code im reflecting user profile page but im only doing that when the user authenticated with a Customer role. It's gonna only work when the user has `Customer` role.
It's so flexible, permission-based auth a little bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add a custom action filter to detect the number of prior events (add pics) within a custom action filter, then route appropriately - like to an "UpdatePlan" controller method.

"OnActionExecuting" filter - before the controller action executes.

This page has an example of a "log" one but yours would detect the count (however you store that) and act accordingly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

This has a .Net 5 example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement a **flexible permission-based authorization** system?

If this is the case, you can **define permissions** for each **operation** grouped by **functional area**.

You can **[click this link](https://www.zehntec.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)** to see how to achieve it.

1. The example in the link defines two functional areas with CRUD permissions.
2. You can define the permissions for uploading files according to your needs.